# Create a double function button

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a Crono. I've tried to create a double function button (Start/Stop) with this code:

```
private void buttonStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (buttonStartStop.Text=="Start")
    {
        timerCrono.Enabled = true;
        buttonStartStop.Text = "Stop";
        buttonResetLap.Text = "Lap";
    }
    if (buttonStartStop.Text == "Stop")
    {
        timerCrono.Enabled = false;
        textBoxLaps.Text += "(Lap " + laps + ")" + "  " + min + ":" + sec + "," + decsec + "\r\n";
        laps++;
        buttonStartStop.Text = "Start";
        buttonResetLap.Text = "Reset";
    }
}
```

But it seems to do the 2 functions when I click on it.

So what could I do to be able to do the 2 separated functions just in one button?

Answer (score 5):

When text is "Start", you execute the first if block.

The first if block sets the text to "Stop".

Then you get to the second if block. Is text "Stop"? It sure is. You just set it to that. So the second if block executes.

Use `else`, as below. When you do that, it will only try the second `if` when the first if's condition is false. So it only does one *or* the other, or maybe neither, but never both.

```
private void buttonStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (buttonStartStop.Text=="Start")
    {
        timerCrono.Enabled = true;
        buttonStartStop.Text = "Stop";
        buttonResetLap.Text = "Lap";
    }
    else if (buttonStartStop.Text == "Stop")
    {
        timerCrono.Enabled = false;
        textBoxLaps.Text += "(Lap " + laps + ")" + "  " + min + ":" + sec + "," + decsec + "\r\n";
        laps++;
        buttonStartStop.Text = "Start";
        buttonResetLap.Text = "Reset";
    }
}
```

TheLethalCoder notes that you can also use a `switch` statement (and with a name like that, I suggest you take him seriously):

```
switch (buttonStartStop.Text) {
    case "Start":
        timerCrono.Enabled = true;
        buttonStartStop.Text = "Stop";
        buttonResetLap.Text = "Lap";
        break;

    case "Stop":
        timerCrono.Enabled = false;
        textBoxLaps.Text += "(Lap " + laps + ")" + "  " + min + ":" + sec + "," + decsec + "\r\n";
        laps++;
        buttonStartStop.Text = "Start";
        buttonResetLap.Text = "Reset";
        break;
}
```

The way to deal with these things is to put a breakpoint at the start of the function, run your program, and step through each line with the F10 key. At each line, carefully examine all the variables the code interacts with. You would see `buttonStartStop.Text` change to `"Stop"`, and then you would see the second `if` statement evaluate `buttonStartStop.Text`, and you would be enlightened.

Comment: Might be worth using a `switch` here instead, though `if else if` is fine too.

Comment: Good idea. Added.

Comment: I hear and obey!

Answer (score 3):

You only want one or the other to run. With your current code, if your first statement evaluates to true, you set the text to "Stop":

```
buttonStartStop.Text = "Stop";
```

then your second statement will also evaluate to true:

```
if (buttonStartStop.Text == "Stop")
```

Since you only want one or the other statement, use `else if` instead of just `if` on your second statement:

```
else if (buttonStartStop.Text == "Stop")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add reference to System.Windows.Interactivity
2. Add usings to xaml:

   ```
   xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
   xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
   ```
3. Add example button code to your control

   ```
   <Button Content="MyButtonWithMultipleClickEvents">
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
               <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                   <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                       <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                           <!--Invoke method if property value is true-->
                           <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding MyStateProperty}" RightOperand="True"/>
                       </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                   </ei:ConditionBehavior>
               </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
               <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MyFirstMethod" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
           </i:EventTrigger>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
               <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                   <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                       <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                           <!--Invoke method if property value is false-->
                           <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding MyStateProperty}" RightOperand="False"/>
                       </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                   </ei:ConditionBehavior>
               </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
               <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MySecondMethod" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
           </i:EventTrigger>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
               <!--After all events change state of MyStateProperty-->
               <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ChangeProperty" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
           </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </Button>
   ```
4. Add code to .cs file and set data context

   ```
   public bool MyStateProperty { get; set; }

   public void MyFirstMethod()
   {
       // your code here
   }

   public void MySecondMethod()
   {
       // your code here
   }

   public void ChangeProperty()
   {
       // change value of state property - allow invoke other method after click
       MyStateProperty = !MyStateProperty;
   }
   ```